# Improving the performance of a DNN model

Tags: deep-learning, speech-synthesis

I have been executing an open-source Text-to-speech system [Ossian](https://github.com/CSTR-Edinburgh/Ossian). It uses feed forward DNNs for it's acoustic modeling. The error graph I've got after running the acoustic model looks like this:
[image: Plot of training vs. validation error of acoustic modeling]
Here are some relevant information:

- Size of Data: 7 hours of speech data (4000 sentences)
- Some hyper-parameters:

  - batch_size       : 128
  - training_epochs  : 15
  - L2_regularization: 0.003

Can anyone point me to the directions to improve this model? I'm assuming it is suffering from over-fitting problem? What should I do to avoid this? Increasing data? Or changing batch-size/epochs/regularization parameters? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is going on with higher regularization parameters?